# Notation q(x) << p(x) in probability

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

I recently read an article on probability theory that use the notation:

q(x) << p(x)

where p(x) and q(x) are two density functions of two distributions. What does the operator << mean in this context? I search around but cannot find the answer and they do not define this notation.

It's in this article: arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03266.pdf, e.g., theorem 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theorem 3.1,  $p_{\theta}$ and $q_{\theta}$ are probability measures rather than density functions. That notation means $q_{\theta}$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $p_{\theta}$, i.e. if $p_{\theta}(A) = 0$ then $q_{\theta}(A) = 0$.